# How to replace occurrence of an element with multiple elements in a sequence?

Tags: clojure

So, I have a list of items. I want to replace each occurrence of an item based on a criteria with a set of elements in it's place.

Ideally, map can let you convert a list of N elements into another list of N elements but here the length will increase as we insert more elements at index where we had other individual elements replaced by a list of elements in place.

Comment: Can you add an example? It sounds like you want `mapcat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proposed by @Lee you can do it using [mapcat](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapcat).

E.g:

```
(mapcat #(if (even? %) [% %] [%]) (range 10))
```

will result into:

```
=> (0 0 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 7 8 8 9)
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `map`, you can use [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce), starting with an empty accumulator collection `[]`.

```
(reduce #(conj %1 (dec %2) %2)
        []
        [1 3 5 7])
```

So here, starting with a collection of odd numbers `[1 3 5 7]`, we are adding extra even numbers into the sequence. Output is:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```